# Is there a phone number I can use to test sending a text message that fails each time?

Tags: sms, system-error

I am wondering whether I could test my application by sending a text message to a phone number that will always fail.

My idea is to see that my application behaves as expected when the sending of a text message fails. So I was hoping that some phone number could be considered invalid by the SMS system and using that number get a *failed* reply from the `sendTextMessage` function.

That way I can relay that error to the user. Having such a bad phone number would be cleaner than having a hack in the application since the hack could end up being a bug.

Comment: I tried my fix line... and it gets accepted as if it were able to text that number?!

Comment: I thought the same thing... not even a form of reply telling me that the number is not accessible. So even less an error at the time I call the `sendTextMessage()` function!

Comment: While this queation is interesting, it is posed from the point of view of a developer. For an end-user, what could possibly be the benefits of such question?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman A user could also want to turn off the messaging processes to verify an application is not going to do something _unwanted_... then turn the normal processing back on.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this and it's working.
This is related to changing the Message centre number.
Here's what you have to do:

1. Go to default Messaging app on your phone.
2. Open settings (generally, the  3-dots button).
3. Click on SIM 1 or SIM 2 SMS Center.

   - In Lollipop, Settings > Text Message (SMS) > SMS Service Center >
     Your SIM.
   - In nougat, Settings > Advanced > SIM 1/SIM 2 SMS Center.
4. First take a screenshot or note the default number entered and then
   change it to any incomplete random number.
5. Save it by clicking the Tick on Top-right corner and now text
   message to any number will fail. Use your numbers to check whether
   message is sending or not.

Whenever you want to send text message, just change the number to default.

Comment: I'm on Android Marshmallow and I do not see anything where I can change the SIM. I have a _More » Settings » More Settings » Text Messages » Manage SIM Card Message_, but that shows nothing. That's pretty much the only reference to the SIM acronym.

Comment: Try Messaging > Additional Settings > Short Message Service Center (SMSC) > Your SIM. These steps are from MIUI, Marshmallow. Or could you share what phone do you have?

Comment: I have a Galaxy j7, I don't see an SMSC entry.

Comment: Here you can see what to do and how to do with images -
 https://www.helpforsmartphone.com/public/en/samsung/galaxy-j7-(2016)/android-6-0/guides/26/Set-up-SMS-Samsung-Galaxy-J7-2016-

Comment: Messaging > More > Settings > More Settings > Text Messages > Message Center

Comment: Ah... interesting. I see the option, it's grayed out on my phone. Message Center has a long number but since it's grayed out, I cannot change it...

Comment: Try Reset to default in Messaging > Settings or Setting the no. in Message Center in the hidden menu accessed by *#*#4636#*#*.

Comment: [ROOT NEEDED] A solution you can try https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=782253